# Value of React state not updating instantly

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a video calling feature into my app and the user's media stream is stored in a React state. However, when I try to access this state in another file (I'm using React Context for this), the stream state hasn't been updated yet and uses the default state value. I learnt, React updates state on the next render rather than instantly but I'm trying to access the stream instantly. However, I'm creating the Peer object inside a function so if I try to delay the stream access for example with a useEffect hook, I then can't use the function outside the hook. Are there any ways I could to this?
Some code samples below:

Within context file:
`const [stream, setStream] = useState(null)`
Where I'm setting the stream:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }).then((currentStream) => {
            setStream(currentStream);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error accessing media devices: ', error);
        });
    }, []);
```

One of my functions (stream logs null):

```js
function callUser(id) {
    console.log(stream)
    const peer = new Peer({ initiator: true, trickle: false, stream })

    peer.on('signal', (data) => {
      socket.emit('call-user', { userToCall: id, signalData: data, from: myID, name })
    })

    peer.on('close', () => {
      socket.off('call-answered')
      setCallAccepted(false)
      setCall(null)
      addCall(false)
      setInfoBarShow(false)
    })

    peer.on('stream', (currentStream) => {
      userVideo.current.srcObject = currentStream
    })

    socket.on('call-answered', (signal) => {
      setCallAccepted(true)

      peer.signal(signal)
    })

    socket.on('call-ended', (endReason) => {
      if (statusRef.current) {
        if (endReason === "declined" || endReason === "ended") statusRef.current.innerHTML = `Call ${endReason}`
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        leaveCall()
      }, 5000)
    })

    connectionRef.current = peer
  }
```

I've tried lots of things such as wrapping the functions in a useEffect hook with the dependency as stream but then the functions aren't globally available. I've tried using selection but that won't work as the component still isn't being re-rendered/refreshed to include the updated state. Nothing works. Peer is using the Simple-Peer package